# is it possible to change the height of a subplot?

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot

I have a total of 4 subplots. 1st and 3rd are the actual Signals and 2nd and 4th are their respective clock signals i.e. they are either 0 or 1. The Problem with subplots is that all the plots are of same height. But i want the height of the clock signals to be small compared to the actual signals. and the respective clock signals should be just below their actual signals. I would summarise my requirements:

1. Reducing the height of the clock signals subplot(i.e the 2nd and the 4th subplot).
2. Reducing the gap between the first two subplots and the last two subplots.

Anyone who could help me out with this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For controlling the margins and gaps between subplots, take a look at the [tight_subplot function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight-subplot) at Mathworks file exchange. I use it almost exclusively even for single-axis plots to get rid of the annoying whitespace around axes.

Comment: I tried this but not helping...it is giving an error   "Undefined function 'tight_subplot' for input arguments of type 'double'." Could you Elaborate a bit more about the solution... @mikkola

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should play a little bit with `gca` and its 'properties'. A very simple example is as:

```
clc, clear, close all
x = -2*pi:0.01:2*pi;
y=sin(x);

subplot(2,1,1);plot(x,y);         % plot the first subplot
subplot(2,1,2);plot(x,y,'r');     % plot the second one

A = get(gca,'position');          % gca points at the second one
A(1,4) = A(1,4) / 2;              % reduce the height by half
A(1,2) = A(1,2) + A(1,4);         % change the vertical position
set(gca,'position',A);            % set the values you just changed
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. The code works fine but if i add more subplots and then increase the size of the first plot then it does not fit in the margins. Is there a way to increase the top margin of a matlab figure ? @NKN

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the size by changing the way that you index the subplots. If you use `subplot(4, 1, 1)`, `subplot(4, 1, 2)` etc. then they will all have the same height. However, if you use `subplot(6, 1, 1:2)`, `subplot(6, 1, 3)` etc. then the first subplot will have twice the height of the second.

To adjust the potition between the plots, you can adjust the `position` property of the axes as follows:

```
figure
t = 1:0.1:10;

for i = 1:4
    switch i
        case 1
            subplot(6, 1, 1:2)
        case 2
            subplot(6, 1, 3)
        case 3
            subplot(6, 1, 4:5)
        case 4
            subplot(6, 1, 6)
    end

    plot(t, sin(i * t));

    if i == 1 || i == 3
        set(gca, 'xtick', []);

        p = get(gca, 'Position');
        % Increase the height of the first and third subplots by 10%
        p_diff = p(4) * 0.1;
        % Increase the height of the subplot, but this will keep the
        % bottom in the same place
        p(4) = p(4) + p_diff;
        % So also move the subplot down to decrease the gap to the next
        % one.
        p(2) = p(2) - p_diff;
        set(gca, 'Position', p);
    end
end
```

Output:

[image]

You can get much more creative with this as required, but this should get you started.

Comment: You are a master. This is exactly I was looking for (a "rowspan" method for changing relative proportions).