# Change the width of a subplot. There is no position property on the Line class

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following figure 
[image]

that I created using the following code

```
%% figures
DateNumObs=datenum(table2array(ADCPCRUM2(1:1678,ColumnYear)),table2array(ADCPCRUM2(1:1678,ColumnMonth)),table2array(ADCPCRUM2(1:1678,ColumnDay)),table2array(ADCPCRUM2(1:1678,ColumnHour)),table2array(ADCPCRUM2(1:1678,ColumnMinutes)),table2array(ADCPCRUM2(1:1678,ColumnSeconds)));
Flipecart=permute(ecart(1:1677,:),[2,1]);
Flipecartreel=permute(ecartreel(1:1677,:),[2,1]);
bottomVel=min(min(min(Magnitude)),min(min(velocityModel*1000)));
topVel=max(max(max(Magnitude)),max(max(velocityModel*1000)));
bottomVer=min(min(Flipecart))
topVer=max(max(Flipecart))

figure
subplot(4,1,1);
FlipMag=permute(Magnitude,[2,1]);
[C,h] =contourf(DateNumObs,1:1:22,FlipMag);
datetick('x','dd/mm/yy','keeplimits','keepticks')
caxis manual
caxis([bottomVel topVel])
c=colorbar;
c.Label.String = 'Horizontal velocity(mm/s)';
xlabel('Date');
ylabel('Depth(m from bottom)');
set(h,'LineColor','none')
title('Observation');

subplot(4,1,2);
[C,h] =contourf(DateNumObs(1:1677),1:1:22,MagMatrixH1*1000);
datetick('x','dd/mm/yy','keeplimits','keepticks')
caxis manual
caxis([bottomVel topVel])
c=colorbar;
c.Label.String = 'Horizontal velocity(mm/s)';
xlabel('Date');
ylabel('Depth(m from bottom)');
set(h,'LineColor','none')
title('Model D1');

subplot(4,1,3)
% x0=10;
% y0=10;
% width=550;
% height=400
gcf=plot(DateNumObs(1:1677),Flipecart(10,:))
% set(gcf,'LineWidth',1,'position',[x0,y0,width,height]) % Part giving the error
datetick('x','dd/mm/yy','keeplimits','keepticks')
caxis manual
caxis([bottomVer topVer])


subplot(4,1,4)
c=colorbar;
plot(DateNumObs(1:1677),Flipecartreel(10,:))
datetick('x','dd/mm/yy','keeplimits','keepticks')
caxis manual
caxis([bottomVer topVer])
```

I am trying to got the normal plot to be the same size as the (blue) contourf plots by using the code which is commented in the code I posted. I got this code from https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/65402-how-to-set-graph-size . 
However, when I try to run it it gives me the following error:

```
Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line/set
There is no position property on the Line class.

Error in StatisticsSOLA (line 315)
set(gcf,'LineWidth',1,'position',[x0,y0,width,height])
```

I also tried [is it possible to change the height of a subplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690179/is-it-possible-to-change-the-height-of-a-subplot) but I get the same error. How do I prevent this error and change the width of the bottom two figures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to set the position of the `axes` and the linewidth of the `line` object in one go, but are not providing the correct handles. Furthermore, don't store the handles of the lines in `gcf`, since this is a reference to the [currently active figure](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html).

Instead you can do:

```
data = rand(100,200); % some data
fig = figure(1); clf;
% first subplot with colorbar
ax(1) = subplot(211);
imagesc(data)
c = colorbar;

% second subplot without colorbar
ax(2) = subplot(212);
p = plot(data(1,:))

% set height and width of second subplot
drawnow                                             % needed to get right position value of ax(1) and ax(2)
ax_pos = [ax(2).Position(1:2) ax(1).Position(3:4)]; % keep ax(2)'s left and bottom position, and set same width and height as ax(1)
set(ax(2), 'Position', ax_pos)
```

**Alternative**

Sometimes it is easier to create colorbar in the second axes, and hide it. This way you don't have to set the positions of the axes yourself.

```
data = rand(100,200); % some data

fig = figure(1); clf;
% first subplot with colorbar
ax(1) = subplot(211);
imagesc(data)
c = colorbar;

% second subplot without colorbar
ax(2) = subplot(212);
p = plot(data(1,:))

c = colorbar;      % draw useless colorbar, 
c.Visible = 'off'; % and hide it
```

Figure should look the same:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first idea you posted works as long as you don't enlarge the picture, then it doesn't have the same length anymore. It's a bit shorter then. EDIT: strange thing: code works, but if you want to see it work full screen, you need to make sure the last figure you plotted was on full screen. Changing from small screen to full screen changes the lengths of the figures

Comment: The second method is more robust, since matlab will resize the subplots accordingly, whereas in the first method you are overriding the position properties meaning they will remain to what you set.